# auto increment receipt number and year

Tags: php, mysql

currently my project receipt number is auto incrementing. eg: 1, 2, 3, ...n
I want to prefix the financial year to differentiate the recept number of every year.
like, 2016-17/1 then 2016-17/2 and so on. 
and year should be change according to financial year (1st april to 31 march assume as one year). 
once the date is 1st april then receipt number should be like 2017-18/1 then 2017-18/2 and so on. 
So, my question is..Is there any code through which i can have the recept no prefix with year.
thank you so much in advance.

```
          <div style="float:left">
                            <label> Receipt No:</label>

                            <input type="text" class="form-control"       style="width: 60% !important; color:#999999;" name="receipt_no" value="<?php
                            $query = mysql_query("SELECT `receipt_no` FROM tsurphus");
                            if(mysql_num_rows($query)>0){
                            $data = mysql_query("SELECT max(receipt_no)+1 FROM tsurphus");
                            $res = mysql_fetch_row($data);
                            echo $res[0];
                            echo $_POST['$res'];
                            }
                            else {
                                echo 1;
                            }
                            ?>" readonly>

                            </div>
```

Comment: **Stop** using deprected `mysql_*` API. Use `mysqli_*` or `PDO` instead

Comment: @Jens can you make your mind and recommend only one of them?

Comment: @YourCommonSense Why?

Comment: @Jens First, if you can't decide yourself, imagine how hard it's for a layman to choose. Second, given what you don't know what to use yourself, it leads to believe that you have no idea of either. Why bother with recommending a tool you aren't familiar with?

Comment: @YourCommonSense Because the main Thing is that OP not should use `mysql_*`

Comment: @Jens that's not the point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So from 1/4 to 31/12 you need <current_year> - <next_year> and from 1/1 - 31/3 <last_year> - <current_year>

```
<div style="float:left">
<label> Receipt No:</label>

<input type="text" class="form-control" style="width: 60% !important; color:#999999;" name="receipt_no" value="<?php


$curr_month = date('m');

if($curr_month >= 4 && $curr_month <= 12){
    $year = date('Y') . '-' . date('y', strtotime("+1 year"));
} else {
    $year = date("Y",strtotime("-1 year")) . '-' . date("y");;
}
echo $year.'/';

$query = mysql_query("SELECT `receipt_no` FROM tsurphus");
if(mysql_num_rows($query)>0){
    $data = mysql_query("SELECT max(receipt_no)+1 FROM tsurphus");
    $res = mysql_fetch_row($data);
    echo $res[0];
    echo $_POST['$res'];
}
else {
    echo 1;
}
?>" readonly>
```

> but the receipt number is continuing even when the financial get change. instead of continuing the receipt number it should reset to 1

You can try to get the max counter for the current year and use it. Something like

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT `receipt_no` FROM tsurphus WHERE recipt_no LIKE '".$year."%'");
```

Comment: @ iliaz thank you so much for ur response. could you please rewrite me the full coding so i can copy and past in my project as im beginner in PHP. thank a lot..!!

Comment: I have edite my ansewer with the full code. If it works for you, please accept it as an answer.

Comment: @ iliaz . now. the year is printing double once i entered a new record Eg: before 2016-17/225 after adding new record 2016-17/2016-17/226 and so on. any idea . thanks a lot.

Comment: Is it from `echo $_POST['$res'];` ?

Answer (score -2):

```
 <?php
   $query = mysql_query("SELECT `receipt_no` FROM tsurphus");
   $fet=mysql_fetch_row($query);
    $num=mysql_num_row($query);
    $rno=$fet['receipt_no'];
   $exp=explode("/",$rno);
   if(date('m')>=4 && date('m')<=12){
      $year=date('Y') . '-' . date('y', strtotime("+1 year"));       
   }else{

      $year=date("Y",strtotime("-1 year")) . '-' . date("y");;
  }
  if($num==0){
      $receiptno= $year."/1";
  }else if(date('m')==4){
       $receiptno= $year."/1";
  }else{
      $receiptno= $year."/".$exp[1]+1;
  }
```

?>

try like this. change the year as you like.

Comment: Not correct. You are only checking for april. What happens in May?

Comment: @premi,   thank you so much both of u for ur response . i copy past ur code no thing is showing. can you please check once and rewrite completely so i can copy and past in my project ... im new in php. thank a lot..!!

Comment: now i edited my code. try it. include order by desc in select query with your primary key id.

Comment: @ premi . . the year is priting double once i entered a new record Eg: before 2016-17/225 after adding new record 2016-17/2016-17/226 and so on. any idea . thanks a lot